# How to find SQL Servers Located in "Relative" Domains

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to find programatically (with C# code) ALL the SQL servers in relative domains - "brothers", "sons" or "father" domain.

It can be done with WMI queries for each domain in the global catalog - but maybe you know about simpler way??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```

which return a DataTable with SQL Server instances available.

Comment: It finds the SQL Servers in the same domain only. I want to find also servers on another domains. Thanks anyway.